# Turn visible feature layers to invisible in ArcGIS-JS-API 3.x

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm trying to turn all visible feature layers to invisible in a map using Javascript and jQuery by clicking into an element.
What is wrong with the following code?

```
$("#grayPic").click(function() {                      
    var allGuys = map.layers;
    var i, currentLayer;
    for (i = 0;  i < allGuys.length; i++) {
       currentLayer = allGuys[i];
       currentLayer.visible = false;
    };
});
```

Comment: Hi, you should tell us what exactly doesn't work. I could imagine that after your code the layers still are visible. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

based on the information provided, I would say that the problem is that the map is not refreshed after changing the visibility of the layers. Just use `map.refresh()` after your loop.

```
$("#grayPic").click(function() {                      
  var allGuys = map.layers;
  var i, currentLayer;
  for (i = 0;  i < allGuys.length; i++) {
    currentLayer = allGuys[i];
    currentLayer.visible = false;
  };
  map.refresh();
});
```

UPDATED:
You are not getting the layers included in the map, that's the reason you're getting a null pointer exception.

1. First, get the layers in a proper way, for example using `map.getLayersVisibleAtScale(map.getScale())`. You can also access the "private" property `map._layers`, which was probably the one you were trying to use.
2. Then with such information, you can perform a loop and set the visibility to false. For that I encourage you to use the method `layer.hide()` instead of set the property to false.

Here the snippet:

```
$("#grayPic").click(function() {
  var layers = map.getLayersVisibleAtScale(map.getScale());
  for (i = 0;  i < layers.length; i++) {
    currentLayer = layers[i];
    if (currentLayer.visible) {
     currentLayer.hide();
    } else {
     currentLayer.show();
    }
  };
})
```

P.S.: I've created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/katahV/pen/eLjzPL) that you can check for further details.

Comment: Sorry ... that does not work either. I am getting the following error message in the console ... Map.js:415 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'visible' of undefined
    at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (Map.js:415)
    at HTMLImageElement.dispatch (jquery-1.12.4.js:5226)
    at HTMLImageElement.elemData.handle (jquery-1.12.4.js:4878)

Comment: Hi John, check the new solution that has to work for you ;)